# How do I calculate the mean of values with the same label given by a mask for multi-dimensional data?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pytorch, mean, mask

My input x is a tensor of [B, C, H, W] dim. B is batch size, C number of channels, H height and W width. I have a mask m of [H, W] dim. For each batch size and each channel I want to use the mask m to calculate the mean of all values in [H, W] with the same label.

For example:

```
B = 2
C = 2
H = 2
W = 3
x = torch.tensor([[[[1,2,3][4,5,6]][[7,8,9][0,1,2]]][[[1,2,3][4,5,6]][[7,8,9][0,1,2]]]])

m = torch.tensor([[0,0,1][0,2,2]])
```

I expect as output:

```
mean = torch.tensor([[2.3,3,5.5][5,9,1.5][2.3,3,5.5][5,9,1.5]])

out = torch.tensor([[[[2.3,2.3,3][2.3,5.5,5.5]][[5,5,9][5,1.5,1.5]]][[[2.3,2.3,3][2.3,5.5,5.5]][[5,5,9][5,1.5,1.5]]]])
```

What I want is the following:

1.) The mean value for each label [mean of label 0, mean of label 1, mean of label 2, mean of label 3, mean of label 4]
2.) I want to replace each value in x with the mean value of its associated label. Output should have the size [B, C, H, W].

I thought to somehow use torch_scatter.scatter_mean.

Comment: Why does your mask tensor contain values > 1?

Comment: Each number in the mask represents a label. I want to calculate the mean across each label.

Comment: This is not at all clear: you want *mean value for each label* that implies across spatial dimensions (and/or channel dimensions)? Now you are saying across each label. So my question comes down to: why do you have duplicates in `m`? If I understand correctly you are looking to get the statistics for labels `{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }`, correct?

Comment: I want to calculate the mean across the label in 2 dimensions. For example, for label 0 I want to calculate the average of all values in H and W dim. So for each label across 2 spatial dimensions. The duplicates make sense because multiple values in x have the same label. Two values in the first row, two values in the second row and one value in the third row has label 0. I want to calculate the mean across those 5 values and replace each of the 5 values with the mean.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example so it is more explicit?

Comment: Sure, I simplified the example in my question.

Comment: Yes, that helps but I meant that you introduce the desired output in the example you gave.

Comment: Ok, I added the expected output to the question as well.

Comment: So in `mean`, the first column corresponds to label `0`, the second to label `1`, and the third to label `2`. Should its shape be `(2, 2, nb_classes=3)` instead of `(4, nb_classes=3`. In this case, how do you get `2.3` for label `0` of batch `0` and channel `0`? This is really not clear.

Comment: The mask m contains 3 0s. That means the mean is calculated from these 3 corresponding values. (1+2+4) / 3 = 7/3 = 2.3 because for batch 0 and channel 0, we have [[1,2,3][4,5,6]].

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to get the mean values for multi-dimensional data. I flatten H and W and then call scatter_mean from torch_scatter. That gives me the mean values per label for each channel and batch.

```
x = x.view(B, C, H*W)
m = m.view(B, 1, H*W)
mean = torch_scatter.scatter_mean(x, m, dim=-1)
```